# Recurring schedule using delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job

Is it possible to do the following using delayed_job:

1. Define a class called `Tasks`
2. Have a method in Tasks run after every 5 minutes: `Tasks.do_processing`
3. When the next 5 minute cycle comes around, then run `Tasks.do_processing` *only* if the *previous* `do_processing` has completed

Is this something I have to create on my own or can delayed_job (or some other gem/plugin) do this?

**Ps.** I know about OS-level cron jobs, but if I used that then it would mean that each time the cron "fired" it would re-load the entire Rails environment, whereas delayed_job only needs to load it once.

Comment: Try https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler instead and set `:allow_overlapping => false`

Comment: More suggestions in this question:  [Is Rails's “delayed_job” for cron task really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632129).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may consider creating a Rake task or other similar standalone processes that takes care of this functionality, and then wrapping it up with [Daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/):

> **What is Daemons?**
>
> Daemons provides an easy way to wrap
>   existing ruby scripts (for example a
>   self-written server) to be run as a
>   daemon and to be controlled by simple
>   start/stop/restart commands.
>
> If you want, you can also use daemons
>   to run blocks of ruby code in a daemon
>   process and to control these processes
>   from the main application.
>
> Besides this basic functionality,
>   daemons offers many advanced features
>   like exception backtracing and logging
>   (in case your ruby script crashes) and
>   monitoring and automatic restarting of
>   your processes if they crash.

Comment: Downvoting because that library's name is so poorly chosen it makes the docs difficult to read and understand what it's doing.  It's like naming your database interface library "driver".

Comment: @Leopd: how's that Brandon's fault?

Comment: @Sergio my vote conveys that I don't think the answer describes a useful way to solve the problem in the OP, for the reasons stated.  It's only about Brandon in that he wrote it.  The point of SO votes is to organize the best solutions to the stated problems.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to do something similar to this :

```
class MyJob

  run_every 1.day

  def perform
    # code to run ...
  end

end
```

then try out this code: https://gist.github.com/1024726

Answer (score 3):

Thought I might add that the [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) gem is an extension of the gist on @kares's answer.

Usage example:

```
class MyTask
  include Delayed::RecurringJob
  run_every 1.day
  run_at '11:00am'
  timezone 'US/Pacific'
  queue 'slow-jobs'
  def perform
    # Do some work here!
  end
end
```

And schedule it. In a rails app, you might put this in an initializer:

```
MyTask.schedule!
```

Answer (score 1):

Been using a version of [this](https://gist.github.com/1648242) in production for a while now for DJ 2.1 . No hackery, uses Delayed Jobs built in hooks. Just make sure you add column named 'queue' to the delayed jobs table, which I believe is something DJ 3 added to the table anyways.

Comment: This looks good for scheduling a job at a specific time (2am UTC in your example), which is not quite the same as what the OP asked: running a task exactly every five minutes e.g. at 12:05, 12:10, 12:15, etc., unless the previous instance is still running. I can set `self.time_to_recur` to `Time.now + 5 minutes`, but that only requeues when the current instance finishes, so it's not an exact schedule. Also there would always be a five-minute gap between jobs, so there's no need to check `job_exists?`.

Comment: Set `time_to_recur` to "Time.now + 5.minutes". There are times when I only want 1 instance of a job, making `job_exists?` quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/codez/delayed_cron_job which is a Delayed Job plugin to set periodical jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Recurring delayed_job:

http://rifkifauzi.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/8/